# Javascript object with getId

Tags: javascript, object, extjs, getter

Working with Ext JS 6.2, I need to create a JS object that has a getId method. Is there any default way to achieve this in JS?

Comment: Yes - create a method, name it `getId`. That's the default.

Comment: `myObject = { getId: () => 'something' }`

Comment: u can try ```method = {  getId () {  }  } ```